# Reverse proxy on Express

Tags: express, phpmyadmin, reverse-proxy, matomo

I am trying to set up a **reverse proxy** in order to serve **PhpMyAdmin** at http://localhost/phpmyadmin endpoint.

Unfortunately I've only managed to redirect `index.php`, any other resource requested by the page is sent directly to http://localhost/, which of course doesn't work.

Here is one of my attempts.

```js
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

// Define a proxy for phpMyAdmin
const phpMyAdminProxy = createProxyMiddleware('/phpmyadmin', {
    target: 'http://admin/', // using the container's name
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: {
        '^/phpmyadmin/': '',
    }
    onProxyReq: (proxyReq, req, res) => {
        proxyReq.setHeader('X-Real-IP', req.ip);
        proxyReq.setHeader('X-Forwarded-For', req.ip);
        proxyReq.setHeader('Host', req.headers.host);
    },
});


app.use('/phpmyadmin', phpMyAdminProxy);
```

I have this line in `config.user.inc.php`, `config.inc.php`, and for the `PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI`environment variable, although changing this didn't seem to have any effects.

```php
$cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] = 'http://admin/';
```

I also would like to do this with **Matomo**, but I have the same problem.

I am considering giving up and putting everything behind **NGIX** instead, but one fewer container would be great too.